# Converting column data into row without any aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table `emp (empno, empname)` like this:

```
empno empname
----------------
1      xxx
2      yyy
3      zzz
..    ....
```

and so on. I have seen some queries but they are using PIVOT/UNPIVOT but if there is aggregate function. I don't want to use aggregate.

I want to convert columns into rows.

```
empno  1    2     3
-----------------------
empnam xxx  yyy   zzz
```

How can I do this in Oracle using SQL?

Comment: why don't you want to use PIVOT ? it looks perfect for your scenario.

Comment: "I don't want to use aggregate." Why? Are you trying to find workaround for duplicate records?

Comment: @Shweta Mishra, if you don't use Pivot, and you go for using Max case, then you would need to write a line for each empno you might have in your table.

Comment: You have two choices in Oracle: use `PIVOT` or use an aggregate. But in any case, if you have a lot of employees you might hit the maximum number of columns in a result anyway (which I think is 1000)

Comment: "I don't want to use aggregate" makes no sense. You have several rows and you want to consolidate the information into a single row. That is pretty much the **definition** of aggregation. It is a common mistake to think that "aggregate" only means `max`, `sum` or `listagg`. `PIVOT` is very much a form of aggregation. So, again: the question itself makes no sense. Do you mean, you want to avoid using things like `max` and `sum`? WHY?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you please help me with query with PIVOT and aggregate, please?

Answer (score 2):

Your options are pretty much to use `PIVOT` explicitly, or to use a pivot query, along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    'empnam' AS empno,
    MAX(CASE WHEN empno = 1 THEN empname END) AS "1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN empno = 2 THEN empname END) AS "2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN empno = 3 THEN empname END) AS "3"
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This query works, but what happens if you have 2000 employee numbers ? would you need to write for each empno a max case statement.

Comment: Right.  And that's not the question which the OP has asked.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez . . . Then you cannot represent the result set in Oracle.  Oracle only supports up to 1000 columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that was precisely my point. That in the first place for a elevated number of records the question does not make sense. For a low number of records, you can build the query as you perfectly did, using MAX case, but for more than 100 I think it does not make sense. That was only my point